# SharePoint 2013-Office - are there known limitations on number of managed metadata values?

Tags: managed-metadata, word, dip

For a customer, we've created a content type (document set) with multiple managed metadata fields. Within the docset, word-content types have been made available which inherit their metadata.
We've noticed that when the sum of the selected MM values (filled in in SharePoint) is higher than 50, Word gives an error on 'missing properties - correct the invalid or missing properties...' in the DIP. As long as the sum is higher than 50, it is not possible to save the document. The user first has to adjust the docset MM, then update the doc, and then set the MM correct again... which isn't really userfriendly.

Is anyone aware of a limitation in office on maximum 50 MM values? Has anyone found a solution/workaround for this?

Comment: The limit is 190 Managed Metadata columns inside a single list! Does indeed sound like a Word issue. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Column

Comment: I'm aware of the SharePoint 2013 limitations, but we're not hitting those limitations. The issue at hand is on the Office-side. I can perfectly select more than 50 items in SharePoint, but then Word won't allow any new updates. So issue is on the Office side here.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to deactivate ParserEnabled Property for SPWeb (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms459891(v=office.15). Then you can add more than 50 values on SharePoint side without syncing this metadata to the documents.
The problem however with this solution is, the whole SPWeb is affected and not only the desired library.
Be aware of the following affects on all libraries in this SPWeb:

- Shown Metadata in Documents are frozen to the time when you disabled the ParserEnabled Property, so they do not get any updates. Furthermore editing properties in the DIP has no effect in SharePoint.
- Required Fields has to be filled in DIP so that saving is allowed. Then you have to input the required fields on sharepoint side again and finally check in the document.
- You can't make use of automated populated Document Property Fields in Word.

For our purpose this solution ended up as too complicated. We are now trying to move properties which could have more than 50 values to a separate list and link them via 1:1 lookup column to the library.